# How to run selective tests from testng.xml

Tags: automation, testng

I have testng.xml in which I have large number of `<test>` tag. I want to execute some of them not all and  I don't want to comment the rest

e.g In my testng.xml, there are three tests

```
<test name="testA">
</test>

<test name="testB">
</test>

<test name="testC">
</test>
```

I want to execute `testA` and `testC` only and i don't want to comment the `testB`

Any suggestion..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a command line switch of: -testnames=testA,testC

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done.  If there are specific tests you do not want to run then you can check out Iannotationtransformer to set the enabled value = false to set specific tests not to run.